# JSF immediate=true, action invoked before or after apply request values phase?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

With immediate="true" on a command button, the action is indeed invoked during apply request values phase and all the remaining phases are skipped. Keeping this in mind, I am wondering exactly when it is invoked. Before or after apply request values phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see it with simple PhaseListener. 
if you have immediate="true", the action method is called during the APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES Phase, so between "beforePhase" und "afterPhase"

Comment: Yes, a debug PhaseListener helped me a lot!.

Answer (score 2):

Once the Apply request values phase has completed (i.e the decode method has been called on all the components in the tree), the UIViewRoot broadcasts the events queued on it, one of which is the Action event queued by the command button.

This happens before any After-Phase Phase Listeners are called for the apply request values phase.